# Django overide python site.py encoding

Tags: django, encoding, python-2.7

I need to override python site.py encoding to utf-8 from my django project

I have edited /lib/python2.7/site.py and change encoding to utf-8 in setencoding() function.
But on each deployment this is again changing to 'ascii'.

Can i set this encoding in my project?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I include this in settings.py and it is working fine.

```
import sys
encoding='utf-8'
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding(encoding)
```